# Is it a coincidence that Hero's Formula defines a Super-elliptic Curve?

Tags: triangles, elliptic-curves

I just realized today that Hero's formula for the area of a triangle: $$A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$ satisfies an super-elliptic curve. Is there any geometric consequence to the fact that the area and the (semi)perimeter of a triangle satisfy an algebraic relation of this kind? Is this a very common occurrence in geometry that I just can't see?

Comment: Seems unlikely, given the very specific value of $s$ that it applies to. I suppose you can think of the right side as a polynomial in $c$ with fixed $a,b.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I was considering something more along the lines of: "Theorem:  given the algebraic curve $A^2=4p(p-2a)(p-2b)(p-2c)$ a point (p,A) lies on the curve iff it is possible to form a triangle with lengths a, b and c with p as the perimeter and A as the area." If so, then a possible follow up would be "Are there other algebraic relationships for polygons, polyhedra?"

Comment: “With lengths $a,b,c$ with $p$ as the perimeter.” The perimeter is always $a+b+c,$ by definition. And the constant term should be $\frac1{16},$ not $4.$

Comment: Other polygon areas are not determined just by the sides. Given four sides, we can determine the maximum and minimum area. For example, with sides $a,b,c,d$ with $a=c,b=d$ you know the polygon is a parallelogram, but the area can be anywhere from $0$ to $ab.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right, $\frac{1}{16}$, sorry about that, it is a mistake I commonly make when I factor by head, I switch multiplication with division. Anyhow, you are right that the classical isoperimetric problem is evidence that the perimeter and the area can be independently varied; nevertheless I believe this does not exclude the possibility of existing an algebraic relationship among the sides and area.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Digging around some more I've found Bretschneider's formula: $K={\sqrt  {(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)-abcd\cdot \cos ^{2}\left({\frac  {\alpha +\gamma }{2}}\right)}}$. I wouldn't consider it impossible expressing the angular dependence explicitly in terms of the sides. I naturally suppose there might be a pattern for all (convex) polygons.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related problem known as the "Congruent number problem". It asks *what are the possible areas of a rational right triangle* (i.e., a right triangle with rational side lengths). A rational number is called *congruent* if it is the area of some rational right triangle.

It turns out that a rational number $D$ is congruent if and only if there is a point $(x,y) \in E(\mathbb{Q})$ where $y \neq 0$ and
$$E : y^2 = x^3 + Dx.$$

The fact that your parameter $s$ depends on $a,b,c$ means that what you are seeing is misleading you. Well in your case you could ask whether a rational number $A$ is the area of a rational triangle. By the formula you quote this is the case if and only if there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$A^2 = \frac{1}{16}(a + b + c)(a + b - c)(a - b + c)(-a + b + c)$$
where you can assume without loss of generality that $a,b,c > 0$ and $a + b > c$ (otherwise this is not a triangle).

Then we consider the semi-algebraic affine surface given by the equation
$$S : (x + y + z)(x + y - z)(x - y + z)(-x + y + z) - 16A^2 = 0$$
and inequalities $x,y,z > 0$ and $x+ y> z$.

One might go out and classify this surface to try do some more in depth study. I searched for points and found that there is a point on this semi-algebraic variety when $0< A \leq 10$ (in contrast to the congruent number case).